# Huge doubt about linear algebra, regarding null space and basis for subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I was doing some exercises to prepare on my exam when I ran into this problem and it got me confused in a way that made me lose more than 6 hours figuring it out.

Basically, the exercise is something like this (this is an example)

Find the basis and dimension of the following subspace in R3:

$
  \begin{cases}
(x,y,z) \in R3 | x+2y+3z =0
\end{cases} $

Now I go , put the coordinates into a "matrix" , then do rref, which is useless in this case, so I take free variables x2 and x3, as the only pivot is x1

$ x3 = k $

$ x2 = s $

so

$ x1 = -2s -3k $

$ x2 = s $

$ x3 = k $

$ x = s * [ -2, 1 0 ] + k * [ -3 0 1 ] $

and i get basis vectors:
$ v1 = [ -2 , 1, 0 ] \\
v2 = [ -3, 0, 1 ] $
And dimension of 2.

Until here it's clear, but what confuses me is that i was using the exact same process to find the Null space of a matrix.

You take the matrix, do RREF, find pivot columns, those are the ones that correspond with the basis columns, from the original matrix, and are also the rank.

Then we have the free variables columns, with no pivot, and those are going to represent the dimension of the Kernel/Null space.

Once i have those columns, i go and put the equations into parametric form and solve exactly like i did now, and instead of the basis for the subspace, i get the null space of the matrix, this got me very confused, same process, two different outputs.

One is the Basis for the Null space (in case of matrix) , and this is the basis for the subspace, starting from an equation, what am i missing ?

In the case of the matrix, the basis is the basis of the column space, which are the columns indicated by the pivots, but in this case with one equation, the basis for the subspace is what would be the null space for a matrix.

How is it possible ?

Thank you

Comment: You have a typo in your equation: The second $x$ should be a $z$. And you should not use capital $X,Y,Z$ when you're using $x,y,z$. But, anyway, what you seem to be missing is that the description of the subspace is precisely giving it as the nullspace of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you, i corrected, i still don't understand what you mean by " description of the subspace is precisely giving it as the nullspace of the matrix" , this makes me very confused. I think the matrix can have a null space but a subspace can't have a nullspace, or where is my confusion coming from ? What is the reason that by doing same operations, one on a matrix and one on an equation, i get different outputs, basis, and null space.  You mean that because the equation is equal to 0 in the definition, the basis of that equation is the null space itself ? And in this case they are the same ?

Comment: When you write, "And dimension of 3", I hope you're not saying the subspace has dimension 3. You found a basis with two elements, so the subspace has dimension 2, not 3.

Comment: Yes i meant 2, 2 vectors = 2 , it was a typo i corrected. Thank you . The main problem here is the difference between those 2 outputs by doing the same operation as i  already explained. The other exercise was only an example.

Comment: "One is the Basis for the Null space (in case of matrix) , and this is the basis for the subspace, starting from an equation, what am i missing" This subspace is in fact the null space of the matrix $[1,2,3]$.

Comment: Yes, but how do i know that , is it because the equation is equal to 0? I know there are 4 subspaces, row space, column space, null space and null space of the row space. So my confusion i think it was that i was trying to find the null space of a subspace, which is impossible , so in my example, what if the equation was equal to 5 ? ( i think then it wouldn't be a subspace because it wouldn't pass the 0 vector test , right ? ) I'm getting  very confused with matrix and subspaces. So a subspace can't have a null space because the  null space it's a subspace itself, of that equation. Right ?

Comment: What is the definition of the nullspace of a matrix? Now, write down that definition for the matrix that littleO and I gave you.

Comment: If someone came up to you on the street one day and asked you what is the null space of the matrix $[1,2,3]$, what would you tell them?

Comment: Well i can't really row reduce that because it's already reduced, after that , i get the vectors that i wrote in my original post, v1=[−2,1,0]v2=[−3,0,1]. But that is my problem, something seems weird to me, this is considered to be the basis for the subspace, not the null space.... so .. i don't understand anything anymore.

Comment: Anyways the definition is the set of vectors that go from the domain but when they get mapped they get mapped to 0, and not to the range.

Comment: The null space of the 3x1 matrix $M=[1,2,3]$ is $\{(x,y,z): 1x+2y+3z=0\}$ when we treat $M$ as a function from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R$. That is $M((x,y,z))=x+2y+3z.$

Comment: I still don't understand, it's the same thing that we started with, it's more confusing now...

Comment: If someone came up to me on the street and asked me what is the null space of the matrix $[1,2,3]$, I'd say it's the set of all vectors $\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ in $\mathbb R^3$ such that $1\cdot x + 2 \cdot y + 3 \cdot z =0$. (In other words, when you multiply the matrix by the vector, you get $0$.)

Comment: Well if i multiply matrix [ 1 2 3] by the vectors that i found v1=[−2,1,0]v2=[−3,0,1], i get 0, so that is the null space, but that is not my doubt, my doubt is why when i have a bigger matrix and i do rref, the null space will be the columns that don't have pivots, and then i do same steps, and find the null space basis. If i want the basis for that matrix, then i have to take the columns represented by the pivots from the original matrix.

Comment: But in this case, with the equation, they ask me for a basis for the subspace, that would mean to take the pivot column from the original matrix, which would mean to only get [ 1 ] , which is weird and wouldn't work. But instead by taking the null space , like you would take it in a normal matrix, in my case i get the basis for the subspace... it's a confusing game of words. Why the null space of my subspace represented by the equation is the basis for the subspace itself ? If i take the null space of a normal matrix, it won't be the basis for that matrix...

Comment: You've identified a matrix whose null space is precisely the subspace you set out to study.  They're the same space, so a basis for one is certainly a basis for the other.

Comment: Ok so all this confusion is because the null space basis is the same as the subspace basis that the exercises asks for ? I think i get it now.. so they're the same thing and i was looking for different things.

Comment: How about if subspace is R4 (x,y,z,t) | x+y+2t=x+3z=0 ? Then i get 2 pivots and 2 free variables, do i take the basis as the rows that are not 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

The subspace in your question is defined as the solution set of a homogeneous linear equation. Recall that the solution set to a system of homogeneous linear equations is precisely the null space of the coefficient matrix. This is true no matter how many equations are in the system, including when there’s only a single equation. In that case, the coefficient matrix only has one row, but the general process of finding its null space is the same: compute its RREF (which might involve no work at all), identify the pivot column, and so on.

Comment: So basically because my linear equation is homogeneous,  it's already set as Ax = 0, meanwhile when i get a matrix and they tell me to find the null space, i have to augment the matrix with the 0 vector myself, in order to find the null space. So when there is a homogeneous linear equation, by default its basis it's always the null space, so the elements that map that equation to the 0 vector. Right ?

Comment: @AndrewM That’s right. Note that when compute the null space of a matrix $A$, there’s no particularly good reason to augment it with a column of zeros before row-reducing. Elementary row operations don’t change that extra column, and it gives you no additional information about the solution once you’ve computed the RREF.

Comment: Yes but in the end, i have to look for the variables whose values will form vectors that if then used as coefficients instead of the variables themselves, they will map my elements to 0, so will map my linear combination to the 0 vector, thus the null space/kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example of this type of exercise:

[image]

Here is how i solved it, and i looked at the teacher's results and are the same.

[image]
My problem again is... i found the null space, and they say it's the basis for the subspace.. but why ? Isn't it the null space ?

And the basis for the subspace should be the rows that are not 0, or the pivot columns equivalent from the original matrix ? What am i missing ?

Comment: If we let $M$ denote the matrix you wrote down, then a vector $x$ is in $V$ if and only if $Mx = 0$, or in other words, if and only if $x$ is in the null space of $M$.  That's the whole point of the way you chose the matrix $M$, to make this true.  So the nullspace of $M$ is exactly $V$. And "find a basis for $V$" and "find a basis for the nullspace of $M$" are just two different ways to ask the same question.

Comment: Because V is a subspace of a vector space and it's basis is the null space of M , which is the null space of the linear transformation, no ? So when i see those exercises to find basis for the subspace given one or two equations, i shall always look for the null space of the matrix of the coefficients of those equations ?

Comment: Please be more careful with your language - you are mixing up "$V$" with "basis for $V$".  But yes, if you are given a subspace defined as the set of vectors satisfying some collection of homogeneous linear equations, then treating as the nullspace of the corresponding matrix is probably a good approach.

Comment: "then a vector x is in V if and only if Mx=0" this because the equation is equal to 0 right ? So we have to find a basis that spans the 0 vector or how should i say, make a linear combination with the existing coefficients, such that, we get the result of that equation, which in this case, it's = 0